# Add relative path to Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle.core.5.5.3 in my WebApi project. I'm able to use links in the xml comments in my model like this:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// This is a test comment
    /// http://www.microsoft.com 
    /// 
    /// </summary>enter code here
```

It is appearing like this:[image: swagger image]

Is there any possibility to add a relative path like this, so that I don't need to change it from server to server?

```
myserver + '/path/doc.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it, as this didn't seem to be related to Swashbuckle. The following [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82d85250-e5ac-48f2-a787-2ca441904c2c/embedding-external-urls-or-hyperlinks-within-xml-comments?forum=csharpide) helped me out in finding the answer.

```
/// This is a test link. <a href="../path/file.html">See details</a><br></br>
```